# java.io.InputStreamReader.ready() blocks execution

Tags: java, concurrency, bufferedreader, blocking

i have one unexpected problem.
in my project i use object of type java.io.bufferedReader to read some data.
it contains readLine() method which reads next line of text from the source.

but the problem with this method is that if source is not ready it blocks execution of the thread which called this method until source has something to read.

fortunately, bufferedReader has ready() method which tells me weather source is ready or not, so i can call it once and a while to see weather there is something to read from the source, and if not to continue doing other jobs.
it mostly works fine, but today i noticed something strange.

in some rare cases when i call ready() method ready method itself blocks the execution.

so i am surprised since ready() method is designed to return true only if it is absolutely sure read* method would not block.

as pointed out by "erwin" below, the real problem is not in java.io.BufferedReader but in underlying reader.

to construct buffered reader i use java.io.InputStreamReader.

even if i do not create BufferedReader, but just use InputStreamReader directly, if i call ready() method, call to that method blocks.

so, how is possible that ready() method blocks, and how to avoid it?

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ready()` method in `BufferedReader` never blocks by itself - you can easily check that in the source code of BufferedReader.

The only case in which the `ready()` method of `BufferedReader` blocks is, if the `ready()` method in the underlying Reader blocks (the one that you passed into the constructor of BufferedReader). So your question should be changed to "[my real Reader class] read() method blocks execution".

For instance, if your underlying reader is a `PipedReader`, there could be an issue because the `ready()` and the `read()` methods are both `synchronized`. If one Thread is blocked for reading from a `PipedReader` and another thread uses `PipedReader.ready()` to check if it can read, then the second thread also blocks until the `read()` on the first thread completes.

Comment: hello erwin,
and thank you for your explanation.
i have not checked underlying reader before, i never remembered to check, until you pointed it out to me.
anyway, underlying reader is object of type "java.io.InputStreamReader", and it is its ready() method which actually blocks when called.

Comment: @SYOBSYOT InputStreamReader reads (again) from an underlying InputStream. So it depends on which type of InputStream. A FileInputStream typically does not block, but on a hard-mounted network file system it might happen. A PipedInputStream could block for the same reason as a PipedReader.

Comment: hello erwin, and thank you for your reply. well, haha, in that case it would be the best if i copy the whole line i use to create my bufferead reader object. so this is the code:
`BUFFERED_INPUT = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(CLIENT.GET_SOCKET().getInputStream()));`
in this code, "GET_SOCKET()" method returns object of type "java.net.Socket", and "getInputStream()" method of socket class returns object of type "java.io.InputStream" which i use to create InputStreamReader, which is then used to create BufferedReader.